# Using a single shared bias for a Fully Connected Layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying out something from a paper[[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf)], where it is required to have a common bias term for all the neurons in the FC layer, instead of individual biases for each neuron.

How do I do it in Tensorflow?

Is it possible to create an FC layer without biases, and finally add `tf.nn.bias_add()`? Is that the right way to do it?
If so, there is no flag to set `tf.nn.bias_add()` as `trainable`. Will it work?

Or any other suggestions?

---

*References:*
[[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf)]: [Deep Reinforcement Learning with Double Q-Learning (Pg.6 right side)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.nn.bias_add(value, bias)` requires `A 1-D Tensor with size matching the last dimension of value`. so just `tf.add` will do:

```python
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32])
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([32, 16]))

#Single bias for all the 16 output
bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1]))

#Works as expected
y =  tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W), bias)

#ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 16 and 1 for 'BiasAdd'
z =  tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(X,W), bias)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried it and it's working!  
So, is it not possible to create a biasless FC layer using `tf.layers.dense()` and add bias to it similarly, instead of creating a variable explicitly (I agree it's a simple task; I'm just asking).

Comment: set `use_bias=False` and then add bias similarly as desribed above.

Comment: Could this added bias be optimized by the gradient?